# CPUsim wombat1 Inc2-pc microinstruction

Tags: increment, simulator, instructions, machine-instruction

In the CPUsim wombat1 machine I noticed a microinstruction Inc2-pc under the increment option. However in the 12 basic (Store,Load,Add,Subtract,Jump etc) machine instructions I cannot seem to find it being used. What is its purpose and also why is its Delta set to 2 and not just 1?

Comment: It's used for instruction fetch - every time you fetch an instruction the PC needs to be incremented by 2.

Comment: then are increment microinstructions only used for fetch seuqences?

Comment: In this specific case, yes, it's only used during instruction fetch.

Comment: say I wanted to implement a stack with push and pop instructions, I would have to use this microinstruction right?

Comment: No - it only operates on the PC.

Comment: couldnt create a new microinstruction to operate on my stack pointer register which will have to be created also, and then add a new hardware module for the stack. Yes?

Comment: Sure - you can create any (micro)instructions you like, but we're now well beyond the scope of your original question.